# In Ember how can I have different html in a component used in multiple places?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I'm trying to make a dropdown component that can have different HTML in the heading/title. I have this so far:

component:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  isOpen: false,
  classNames: ['dropdown-toggle'],

  mouseEnter: function() {
    if (!this.get('isOpen')) {
      this.set('isOpen', true);
    }
  },

  mouseLeave: function() {
    if (this.get('isOpen')) {
      this.set('isOpen', false);
    }
  },

  click: function() {
    if (this.get('isOpen')) {
      this.set('isOpen', false);
    }
  }
});
```

component template:

```
{{title}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
{{#if isOpen}}
  {{yield}}
{{/if}}
```

application template:

```
  {{#dropdown-menu title=fullName}}
  <ul role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="divider hidden-xs"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  {{/dropdown-menu}}
```

So the dropdown initially starts closed, displaying only the title (which is passed in) and some markup, displaying a thing to hover over and the content is revealed by some actions.

I'd like to be able to specify that heading/title markup each time I use the component but I can't figure out how.

For example maybe I want another dropdown somewhere on the page but I'd like to include an image in the header or some other markup.

Is this possible or would I have to make separate components for each type of dropdown? Like `{{generic-dropdown}}` and `{{image-dropdown}}`

Comment: Use `toggleProperty`. Anyway, I'm confused by this question. Could you give more concrete examples? What do you mean by "heading markup where the button is" and "dropdowns", and "headings"?

Comment: Yes sorry this isn't exactly my code I am using toggleProperty. I will update the example.

Comment: Create an abstract component, have two subclasses which implement the difference.

Comment: @Marcin could you elaborate on that? Do you mean I can have generic-dropdown and then extend that? What would extending that look like? `Ember.GenericDropdownComponent.extend()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your project done quickly, then yes, just implement `{{button-dropdown}}` and `{{image-dropdown}}`.

Or, you could consider an approach where you implement the desired headers as components themselves:

> button-header/template.hbs

```
<button {{action 'toggle'}}>{{content}}</button>
```

> image-header/template.hbs

```
<img src="{{content}}">
```

Now you can define the component as

> test-show/template.hbs

```
{{#component header content=content}}
    {{yield}}
{{/component}}
```

This uses the new `component` helper.

You would call this as

> my-template.hbs

```
{{#test-show header='image-header' content='kitten.png'}}
    This is some content.
{{/test-show}}
```

Untested.

Comment: Sorry I updated my example while you were answering... could you update your answer please to reflect the updated code in my question?

Comment: Also can you point me to the docs for the component helper? I can't find it.

Comment: I found the docs in the api guide here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_component